# Powershell: suppress output when regex replace found no match

Tags: regex, powershell

by default powershell "-replace [regex]" generate an output even no replacement was done.
how can i suppress this output cause this will make it larger in size with lot of duplicate and extra data while using more than 4000 names as input

example script:

```
"allal","farid","widad"|%{
     $name=$_;"a","i","e","o","y","u"|%{
        ([Regex]"($_)").Replace($name,"`$1`$1",1)  }
}
```

output:

```
aallal
allal     #must not exist in output
allal     #must not exist in output
allal     #must not exist in output
allal     #must not exist in output
allal     #must not exist in output
faarid
fariid
farid     #must not exist in output
farid     #must not exist in output
farid     #must not exist in output
farid     #must not exist in output
widaad
wiidad
widad     #must not exist in output
widad     #must not exist in output
widad     #must not exist in output
widad     #must not exist in output
```

Wanted Method: Suppress The output when No Match exists.
Inefficient & Unwanted Method below:

```
$output|sls "aa|ii|ee|oo|yy|uu"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to return the information if there was a match or not with `Regex.Replace` method. You can only compare strings before and after regex replacing.

I suggest using the `[aeuioy]` pattern directly in the `Regex.Replace` method to replace all occurrences:

```
 "allal","farid","widad"|%{
>>      ([Regex]"[aoueiy]").Replace($_,"`$&`$&")
>> }
aallaal
faariid
wiidaad
```

With Powershell 7, you can use

```
PS> "allal","farid","widad"|%{
>>      $name=$_;"a","i","e","o","y","u"|%{
>>         $name.Contains($_) ? ([Regex]"$_").Replace($name,'$&$&', 1) : ''  }
>> } | Where-Object { $_ }
aallal
faarid
fariid
widaad
wiidad
```

Here, `$name.Contains($_)` makes sure there is a vowel in the `$name` (so, there will definitely be a match), and if yes, the `Regex.Replace` is run, else, an empty string is returned, and the subsequent `Where-Object { $_ }` removes those empty strings.

Comment: you used filtering,although i didn't understand ps 7 method here is an easy one.  `"allal","farid","widad"|%{$name=$_;"a","i","e","o","y","u"|%{$vowel=$_;$_}|?{$name -like "*$vowel*"}|%{([Regex]"($_)").Replace($Name,"`$1`$1",1)}  }`

Comment: @Kardof Z. Very nice one.